# How do i place my toggle button on the right

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to place my toggle button on the right but cant seem to find a solution to my problem

```html
Row(
                          children: [
                            Text("Enable QR Code"),
                              Switch(value: isSwitched, onChanged:(value){
                              setState(() {
                                isSwitched=value;
                                print(isSwitched);
                              });
                            },
                              activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                              activeColor: Colors.green,
                            ),
                            ],
                           ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use row `mainAxisAlignment` property

```
Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Enable QR Code"),
                              Switch(value: isSwitched, onChanged:(value){
                              setState(() {
                                isSwitched=value;
                                print(isSwitched);
                              });
                            },
                              activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                              activeColor: Colors.green,
                            ),
                            ],
                           ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Row(
                          children: [
                            Text("Enable QR Code"),
                            Spacer(),
                              Switch(value: isSwitched, onChanged:(value){
                              setState(() {
                                isSwitched=value;
                                print(isSwitched);
                              });
                            },
                              activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                              activeColor: Colors.green,
                            ),
                            ],
                           ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In Row widget you can use mainAxisAlignment property to set alignment to child widgets so in your case just add:
`mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,`

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text("Enable QR Code"),
          Switch(value: isSwitched,
            onChanged:(value){
            setState(() {
              isSwitched=value;
              print(isSwitched);
            });
          },
            activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

- start: Place the children as close to the start of the main axis as possible
- end: Place the children as close to the end of the main axis as possible.
- center: Place the children as close to the middle of the main axis as possible.
- spaceAround: Place the free space evenly between the children as well as half of that space before and after the first and last child.
- spaceBetween: Place the free space evenly between the children.
- spaceEvenly: Place the free space evenly between the children as well as before and after the first and last child

[image: MainAxisAlignment]

Answer (score 0):

Either you should wrap text inside Expanded widget or use Switch List Tile and use property controlAffinity.

```
Row(children: [
      Expanded(child: Text("Enable QR Code")),
      Switch(value: isSwitched, onChanged:(value){
          setState(() {
             isSwitched=value;
             print(isSwitched);
          });
         },
         activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
         activeColor: Colors.green,
        ),
   ],
 ),
```

Comment: i dont want text to be on right just toggle button